# Selecting area from webcam to screenshot and capture in p5js not working

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I wanted to take a screenshot from the selected area of the camera when I press the "Add screenshot" button but nothing appears except an empty canvas, also another "Add capture" button will add another canvas to keep capturing the selected area of the camera when I press it but also nothing appears except an empty canvas. I wonder what is actually happening when I press the button?
[link to the script in p5js editor](https://editor.p5js.org/rvirtualea9/sketches/Hi01YkJQ3)

```
let video;
let shots = [];
let captures = [];
let button1;
let button2;
let canvas1, canvas2;
let lastmouseX = 0, lastmouseY = 0;
let firstmouseX = 0, firstmouseY = 0;

const s1 = p => {
  p.setup = () => {
    console.log("asd");
    // video
    video = p.createCapture(p.VIDEO);
    video.hide();
    // canvas
    canvas1 = p.createCanvas(700, 500);
    canvas2 = p.createGraphics(700, 500);
    // button1
    button1 = p.createButton("Add screenshot");
    button1.size(200, 100);
    button1.mousePressed(() => {
      shots.push(new p5(s2, "screenshotbox"));
    });
    // button2
    button2 = p.createButton("Add Capture");
    button2.size(200, 100);
    button2.mousePressed(() => {
      captures.push(new p5(s3, "capturebox"));
    });
  };
  p.draw = () => {
    canvas2.clear();
    p.image(video.get(), 0, 0, 700, 500);
    canvas2.fill(175, 100);
    canvas2.rect(firstmouseX, firstmouseY, lastmouseX-firstmouseX, lastmouseY-firstmouseY);
    if (p.mouseIsPressed) {
      canvas2.clear();
      if (!(p.mouseX > 710 || p.mouseX < -10 || p.mouseY < -10 || p.mouseY > 510)) {
        canvas2.rect(firstmouseX, firstmouseY, p.mouseX-firstmouseX, p.mouseY-firstmouseY);
      }
      else {
        canvas2.rect(firstmouseX, firstmouseY, lastmouseX-firstmouseX, lastmouseY-firstmouseY);
      }
    }
    p.image(canvas2, 0, 0);
  };
  p.mousePressed = () => {
      if (!(p.mouseX > 710 || p.mouseX < -10 || p.mouseY < -10 || p.mouseY > 510)) {
        (p.mouseX > 700) ?
          firstmouseX = 700 :
          (p.mouseX < 0) ?
            firstmouseX = 0 :  
            firstmouseX = p.mouseX;
        (p.mouseY > 500) ?
          firstmouseY = 500 :
          (p.mouseY < 0) ?
            firstmouseY = 0 :  
            firstmouseY = p.mouseY;
      }
      // console.log("r", p.mouseX, p.mouseY);
      // console.log("nr", firstmouseX, firstmouseY);
    };
    p.mouseReleased = () => {
      if (!(p.mouseX > 710 || p.mouseX < -10 || p.mouseY < -10 || p.mouseY > 510)) {
        (p.mouseX > 700) ?
          lastmouseX = 700 :
          (p.mouseX < 0) ?
            lastmouseX = 0 :  
            lastmouseX = p.mouseX;
        (p.mouseY > 500) ?
          lastmouseY = 500 :
          (p.mouseY < 0) ?
            lastmouseY = 0 :  
            lastmouseY = p.mouseY;
      }
      // console.log("r", p.mouseX, p.mouseY);
      // console.log("nr", lastmouseX, lastmouseY);
    };
}

new p5(s1, "scripts");

const s2 = p => {
  p.setup = () => {
    let w = lastmouseX-firstmouseX;
    let h = lastmouseY-firstmouseY;
    p.createCanvas(150, 150);
    p.image(video.get(firstmouseX, firstmouseY, w, h), 0, 0, 150, 150);
  };
};

const s3 = p => {
  let w, h;
  let fx, fy;
  p.setup = () => {
    w = lastmouseX-firstmouseX;
    h = lastmouseY-firstmouseY;
    fx = firstmouseX;
    fy = firstmouseY;
    p.createCanvas(150, 150);
  };
  p.draw = () => {
    p.image(video.get(fx, fy, w, h), 0, 0, 150, 150);
  };
};
```

Comment: Seems to work in Chromium 93. What browser are you using?

Comment: @PaulWheeler I'm using Microsoft Edge but I tried it in Google Chrome too and it still doesn't work, when I press the button the second time it won't work, are you trying it in the p5js editor link?

Comment: Yes, using the p5js editor. I intermittently see an issue where if I click screenshot first, then capture I get the issue of the blank canvas. But if I refresh the page and try again it works.

Comment: It's great you're sharing the code and explaining what you're trying to achieve. I am bit confused by the need of 3 separate p5.js sketches. Is the capture button for a short video capture ? I wonder if the screenshot functionality could be achieved simpler (e.g. one sketch that grabs a PImage copy of the selection/region of interests and appends it's <canvas /> element to the page).

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza
The capture button will make another canvas to keep capturing the selected area on the webcam until the script ends. Btw, isn't PImage from Processing? I'm using p5js but I don't really know how to use Processing, I'm sorry.

Comment: @PaulWheeler
Do you know why does it happen like that? I wonder what is actually happening when I press the button?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot get the issue to reproduce consistently enough to diagnose. However I did discover that your code only works if you create the selection area by clicking and dragging down and to the right (i'll detail this issue in an answer).

Comment: @rviretual_001 unfortunately I wasn't able to respond in a timely manner. I probably should have used p5.Image instead of PImage. Paul's answer is great (+1) (no need for me to post additional details)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One potential issue you have is that if the mouse position when the mouse button is released has an x or a y value **less than** the mouse position when the button was pressed then you will wind up with a negative width or height for the portion of the image you are drawing, which isn't going to work. Here's a simple fix:

```
const s2 = p => {
  p.setup = () => {
    let w = p.abs(lastmouseX-firstmouseX);
    let h = p.abs(lastmouseY-firstmouseY);
    p.createCanvas(150, 150);
    p.image(video.get(p.min(firstmouseX, lastmouseX), p.min(firstmouseY, lastmouseY), w, h), 0, 0, w, h);
  };
};

const s3 = p => {
  let w, h;
  let fx, fy;
  p.setup = () => {
    w = p.abs(lastmouseX-firstmouseX);
    h = p.abs(lastmouseY-firstmouseY);
    fx = p.min(firstmouseX, lastmouseX);
    fy = p.min(firstmouseY, lastmouseY);
    p.createCanvas(150, 150);
  };
  p.draw = () => {
    p.image(video.get(fx, fy, w, h), 0, 0, w, h);
  };
};
```

When computing the width and height of the selected region we use the absolute value of the difference, and when finding the left and top coordinates we use the lesser of the two values x or y values respectively.

https://editor.p5js.org/Kumu-Paul/sketches/DrKz9rYbp